# Auto deployment with GitHub PHP Composer and Bash

Tags: php, linux, bash, ubuntu, composer-php

I'm having an issue getting Composer to run on my deployment server through PHP. I have (or will have) a webhook set up with GitHub that will inform me of and accepted pull requests, then auto deploy to the appropriate server.

The issue is coming from the bash line `(cd ${localFolder} && composer install --no-ansi --no-dev --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader)`, it is not giving any errors or output it is as if it was never called. Every other line in the script runs fine, even commands that come after the stubborn one. I have also tried to run the script without any options and with the folder locations hard coded with the exact same results.

When I try and test the command by executing `sudo -H -u www-data bash -c 'echo "./download_project.sh 12345678912345 git_branch git_repo'` in the shell it runs fine and to completion.

PHP Code:

```
$data = json_decode(utf8_encode(file_get_contents("data.json")));
$command = "/var/www/download_project.sh" . " " . uniqid() . " " . $data->deployTable[$deploy]->branch . " " . $data->deployTable[$deploy]->repository;
echo ($command . "</br>");
echo shell_exec($command);
```

Bash Code:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $(basename $0) [guid] [branch] [repository]"
    exit 1
fi

working="/var/www/"
guid=$1
branch=$2
repository=$3
localFolder="${working}temp/"
localFile="${working}temp.zip"

#clone the appropriate branch and repository to the /var/www/temp folder
#result: functions as expected
git clone -b $branch git@github.com:ORGANIZATION/$repository.git $localFolder

#moves the sql folder out of /var/www/temp and onto /var/www to be used for db creation and/or migration
#result: functions as expected
mv "${localFolder}sql" "${working}sql"

#removes /var/www/temp/doc as it is not needed or wanted for production
#result: functions as expected
rm -rf "${localFolder}doc"

#downloads all dependencies  into the /var/www/temp/vedor folder
#result: nothing happens
(cd ${localFolder} && composer install --no-ansi --no-dev --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader)
```

N.B. GUID will be used in the future for archiving purposes.

Comment: What happens if you break the cd and the composer install into seperate lines in your bash code? Also, does this work if you run the script manually line by line?

Comment: @MikelBitson I get the same result if I break the cd. If I run the commands line by line in the shell it works fine as myself or as www-data. If I only run the stubborn line in the script I get the same non-result.

Comment: Upvoted you for visibility, hopefully someone can lend a hand. I'm not sure why this isn't working- I run a very similar script for my sites. Was composer installed globally on the server?

Comment: @MikelBitson Yes Composer is installed globally and managed separately. Thanks for the vote.

Comment: You are not describing ANY observation of WHAT WENT WRONG. You point to the line in the shell script that has "an issue", stating "it is not giving any errors and every other line runs fine, even commands that come after the stubborn one.", so the script isn't failing or stopping, but WHAT THE HELL DIDN'T WORK?

Comment: @Sven I have edited the post. In essence it is as though the command is not there. I have no output or any result from the command, which is suppose to download and install all my dependencies.

Comment: Could you give a brief summary of what your process is supposed to do, step by step? E.g. I see it is supposed to clone something. But if you could be a bit more specific (especially about the directory structure and such) that would be very helpful. Also don't wrap the `cd && composer install` in `()`, as that will run it in a subshell which is not going to make things easier.

Comment: @alcohol I have added comments to each line in the bash script detailing the expected result and the actual result. I have kept the the wrap of the cd as to maintain the original essence of the question, but the script was originally written without the wrap and had the exact same result.

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend moving the `cd && composer install` out of the subshell you are forcing it into (read: remove the enclosing `()`).

Second, I would temporarily modify the shebang to read `#!/bin/bash +x` so you can run the script in a sort of debugging mode.

Then show us the outcome of a run.